# mqtt over socket in django-channels

Tags: django, websocket, mqtt, django-channels, paho

I am trying to start a mqtt broker over websocket in django-channels to publish data over specific topics to authorized users.
I have defined a url to filter mqtt request in a specific consumer where I am accepting the socket request.
This all part is working fine but when I am establishing a mqtt connection the socket is restarting again and again, and I don't have any idea why this is happening!?
and also it's a bit confusing how will i send the message from my views.

**Code snippets:**

routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
     re_path(r'ws/data/(?P<room_name>\w+)/(?P<auth_data>\S+)/$',consumer.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
     re_path(r'mqtt', consumer.ChatTwoConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

consumer.py

```
class ChatTwoConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
def connect(self):
    print('here')
    self.accept()
```